# Please continue to commit to the Music Fans Area 51 proposal

Tags: discussion, area51

A while ago, we decided we wanted to support the Music Fans proposal on Area 51. The proposal still needs about 50 more people to support it to make it into beta, but it's been growing very slowly for several months and is getting a little close to being closed due to lack of activity. If you haven't committed to Music Fans yet, please do so!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans

Comment: 36 commitments to go. It would be thrilling to get this site into beta.